# Bad request 400

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller

I have Spring/Hibernate/MVC/Maven application.
I want to send an ID of my object through request URI.

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editCase", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEditCase(@PathVariable("id") Long id, ModelMap model) {

    System.out.println("reached!");
     ....
    return "editCase";
}
```

But when I try to retrieve this page, I get 400 request error.

What is the reason for this error? How is that my request malformed? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `PathVariable` so you need to declare `id` in `value`. E.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editCase/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Actually, the way I am using it, I should of added: @RequestParam("id")...  thanks once again :)